# javascript - create an array with the history of form values

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I want to use a `<form>` for a chat. I have an `onclick="Input()"` event triggering this function:

```
function Input() {
    var chatArr = [];
    var chat = document.getElementById("chat").value;
    chatArr.push(chat);
    chatArr.join(", ");
    console.log(chatArr);
}
```

but the array is only holding the last typed values.

how do I track the history of all words?

Comment: try putting this line var chatArr = []; before function Input() and see if it works

Comment: `console.log` doesn’t necessarily log the current state of an object. For arrays use `console.log(chatArr.slice());` to create a copy of the array to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a new array everytime the method is called

```
var chatArr = [];

function Input() {
    var chat = document.getElementById("chat").value;
    chatArr.push(chat);
    console.log(chatArr.join(", "));
}
```